# Adding list of figures and list of table to table of contents in ltx

Tags: table-of-contents, lyx, tocbibind

Is is possible to add the `list of figures` and `list of tables` to the `TOC` in document `book standard` class?

I have added the `\usepackage{tocbibind}` but the below error was being prompted in lyx:

[image]

Comment: Well, it seems not to be installed. What is your distribution?

Comment: I have used another alternative `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}` .. what do you mean by distribution?

Comment: MiKTeX or  TeX Live?

Comment: @Bernard - MiKTeX

Comment: Install tocbibind with MiKTeX Package Manager.